# What is the fastest way to get a large number of time ranges using Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I have about 100 GB of time series data in Hadoop. I'd like to use Spark to  grab all data from 1000 different time ranges.

I have tried this using Apache Hive by creating an extremely long SQL statement that has about 1000 `'OR BETWEEN X AND Y OR BETWEEN Q AND R'` statements.

I have also tried using Spark. In this technique I've created a dataframe that has the time ranges in question and loaded that into spark with:

```
spark_session.CreateDataFrame()
```

and

```
df.registerTempTable()
```

With this, I'm doing a join with the newly created timestamp dataframe and the larger set of timestamped data.

This query is taking an extremely long time and I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially if the data is not partitioned or ordered in any special way, you or Spark need to scan it all no matter what.

I would define a predicate given the set of time ranges:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Range

val ranges: List[Range] = ??? // load your ranges here
def matches(timestamp: Int): Boolean = {
  // This is not efficient, a better data structure than a List
  // should be used, but this is just an example
  ranges.contains(_.contains(timestamp))
}

val data: RDD[(Int, T)] = ??? // load the data in an RDD
val filtered = data.filter(x => matches(x.first))
```

You can do the same with DataFrame/DataSet and UDFs.

This works well if the set of ranges is provided in the driver. If instead it comes from a table, like the 100G data, first collect it back in the driver, if not too big.

Answer (score 0):

Your Spark job goes through 100GB dataset to select relevant data.
I don’t think there is big difference between using SQL or data frame api, as under the hood the full scan happening anyway.

I would consider re-structuring your data, so it is optimised for specific queries.

In your cases partitioning by time can give quite significant improvement (for ex. HIVE table with partitioning).
If you perform search using the same field, that has been used for partitioning - Spark job will only look into relevant partitions.